# An SEO agency suggests removing a keyword from the title of a ranking page to get another page to rank. Is this good advice?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking, title, page

I'm technically responsible for a small website.  There are two pages which have a title containing the same word ("Stammbücher"). Now an SEO  agency is telling me that this is a severe problem and we should remove the word from the title of the first page.

I'm worried about whether this is a good idea. The main page, where they want the word to be removed, is the one ranking better for that word. The other page (with the longer URL) has a much lower ranking for that word, but on the other hand, much better content dealing with this word.

Is there any definite answer on whether the title of the first page should be changed to remove that particular keyword?

Edit:
These are the titles of the two pages:
A: Stammbücher und Gästebücher für die Hochzeit
B: Stammbücher für Standesamt, Hochzeit und Kirche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be a good idea. In the case

- titles of both pages are same (not similar),
- content of both pages is (very) similar,
- both pages cannibalize each other rankings

than yes, this **is** a good idea.

Comment: So if I understand you right: when the titles are not identical (page A is: Stammbücher und Gästebücher für die Hochzeit and page B is: Stammbücher für Standesamt, Hochzeit und Kirche) it is not a good idea, right?

Comment: In this case the way to go should be to consolidate both pages to the single one, because they partly cannibalize each other rankings

Answer (score 0):

No, I don’t find it a good idea. Because these days changing title of a ranked page is not so good idea and if they want to rank another page then the content is direct method for that.
Because in 2018 Google ranking algorithm updates, google clearly said that they have changed some frequency and values of ranking factors like H1 and H2 tags etc but at the botton they said that best value content will overlap all these ranking factors..
So in my opinion, changing ranked page title is not a worthy idea. 
Just need to focus on other page content for ranking.